# Giving an exact position to a set of selected layers Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design

[image]

I have selected an image made out of multiple layers but I want it to have an exact distance from left, right, up and down. so far, I can only use my eyes to move the picture but how to set an exact distance for the layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use guides in your position with your distance you want

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: @James - [place a guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/grid-guides.html)